# Defining a single jQuery function for separate DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several jQuery click functions- each is attached to a different DOM element, and does slightly different things...

One, for example, opens and closes a dictionary, and changes the text...

```
$(".dictionaryFlip").click(function(){
    var link = $(this);
    $(".dictionaryHolder").slideToggle('fast', function() {
        if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
            link.text("dictionary ON");
        }
        else {
            link.text("dictionary OFF");
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
        <div class="dictionaryHolder">
            <div id="dictionaryHeading">
                <span class="dictionaryTitle">中 文 词 典</span> 
                    <span class="dictionaryHeadings">Dialog</span>

                    <span class="dictionaryHeadings">Word Bank</span>                       

            </div>
        </div>

<p class="dictionaryFlip">toggle dictionary: off</p>
```

I have a separate click function for each thing I'd like to do...

Is there a way to define one click function and assign it to different DOM elements? Then maybe use `if else` logic to change up what's done inside the function?

Thanks!

---

Clarification:

I have a `click` function to 1) Turn on and off the dictionary, 2) Turn on and off the menu, 3) Turn on and off the minimap... etc... Just wanted to cut down on code by combining all of these into a single click function

Comment: please share your html also

Comment: what is the relationship between `dictionaryFlip` and `dictionaryHolder` elements

Comment: @ArunPJohny `dictionaryFlip` is the text "Toggle Dictionary" that you can click to toggle the `dictionaryHolder` CSS element on and off...

Comment: using is else conditions will be a mess to maintain later... if your click functions are non-related keep them separate

Comment: How about defining an outside function that can be called by any click handler ?

Comment: Following your clarification, if these tasks share a common procedure you could parameterize it. Say pass a "dictionary", "menu" or "minimap" parameter to a toggle.

Comment: @JamesPoulson What if the procedures are different? Can I use if/else to run the correct procedures based on the DOM element?

Comment: It really depends. If you can describe in pseudo language what each procedure does then perhaps they can be combined. Otherwise, it's usually best to avoid if else structures. There are alternatives which are more flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course define a single function and use it on multiple HTML elements. It's a common pattern and should be utilized if at all possible!

```
var onclick = function(event) {
    var $elem = $(this);
    alert("Clicked!");
};

$("a").click(onclick);
$(".b").click(onclick);
$("#c").click(onclick);

// jQuery can select multiple elements in one selector
$("a, .b, #c").click(onclick);
```

You can also store contextual information on the element using the `data-` custom attribute. jQuery has a nice `.data` function (it's simply a prefixed proxy for `.attr`) that allows you to easily set and retrieve keys and values on an element. Say we have a list of people, for example:

```
<section>
    <div class="user" data-id="124124">
        <h1>John Smith</h1>
        <h3>Cupertino, San Franciso</h3>
    </div>
</section>
```

Now we register a click handler on the `.user` class and get the id on the user:

```
var onclick = function(event) {
    var $this = $(this), //Always good to cache your jQuery elements (if you use them more than once)
        id = $this.data("id");

    alert("User ID: " + id);
};

$(".user").click(onclick);
```

Comment: This sounds like an interesting approach for simplifying logic. I was going to say it would be triggered by any click until I saw the selector you used at the bottom. When you say cache, the jQuery object is being saved right ? What's the difference between a `var this` and `var $this` ?

Comment: Yes, the object is being saved. You see, jQuery functions are called in the context of native DOM elements, this means 'this' is the actual DOM Element and not a jQuery object. To use all of jQuery's goodness on this element we need to create a new instance of jQuery on the DOM element. This is why we do '$(this)' inside the function. So the difference between 'this' and '$this' is a native DOM element (document.body or getElementById both return native DOM elements) vs a jQuery object. The reason why we create the '$this' variable is to save having to create multiple jQuery instances.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Just an added note. If anyone is reading this do make sure you put the handler inside `$(document).ready(//...`. Have forgotten to do this yet again and hopefully it will become second nature :p

Comment: Would redirecting to other functions from the onclick be considered good practice ? Such as `var logout = function(){ $.ajax({ url : "/logout", //...` and `logout`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple pattern

```
function a(elem){
    var link = $(elem);
    $(".dictionaryHolder").slideToggle('fast', function() {
        if (link.is(":visible")) {
            link.text("dictionary ON");
        }
        else {
            link.text("dictionary OFF");
        }
    });
}

$(".dictionaryFlip").click(function(){a(this);});
$(".anotherElement").click(function(){a(this);});
```

Comment: I assume you mean `$(".dictionaryFlip").click(function() { a(this); });` instead. The code you have is invalid because `a` doesn't return a function and `this` won't refer to the selected element(s).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do something like:

```
var f = function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if($this.hasClass('A')) { /* do something */ }
  if($this.hasClass('B')) { /* do something else */ }
}

$('.selector').click(f);
```

and so inside the f function you check what was class of clicked element

and depending on that do what u wish

Answer (score 0):

For better performance, you can assign only one event listener to your page. Then, use `event.target` to know which part was clicked and what to do.

I would put each action in a separate function, to keep code readable.

I would also recommend using a unique Id per clickable item you need.

```
$("body").click(function(event) {
    switch(event.target.id) {
    // call suitable action according to the id of clicked element
        case 'dictionaryFlip':
            flipDictionnary()
        break;
        case 'menuToggle':
            toggleMenu()
        break;
        // other actions go here
    }
});
function flipDictionnary() {
    // code here
}
function toggleMenu() {
    // code here
}
```

cf. Event Delegation with jQuery http://www.sitepoint.com/event-delegation-with-jquery/